# Find period in a Time Series

Tags: python, time-series, period, periodicity

I have the following Time Series:

[image]

From the plot I can notice that data are periodic, since the peaks(let's call them valley since I am talking about the one that goes down) have more or less the same distances. Is there a way to find what is the period, expressed as the number of points between each peak. I don't need a very precise number, an estimate would be enough.

Comment: You could use a FFT (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft.html) to convert this to frequency domain and the peak value should be the frequency you are looking for.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. It produce the highest spike on 0. Maybe the problem is that each peak in the figure contains lot of points not just one

Comment: That is due to the "DC offset" (non-zero systematic shift) of the signal. You can either use a high-pass filter or simply ignore the bins close to zero.

Comment: The highest peak will be 0 for this data since everything is above 0.  the second peak is what you're really looking for.  Something you can do to get rid of that peak at 0 is to subtract your data set by the average.  This should get rid of the peak at 0 and your second peak should be clearly visible..